# Extender timeOut desde web config de .Net web app con connectionStrings

Tags: sql, .net, timeout, web.config

Tengo una web app en .Net y tengo un error al intentar consumir un procedimiento almacenado. El mensaje de error que estoy recibiendo es "Se agotó el tiempo de espera de ejecución. El período de tiempo de espera transcurrió antes de la finalización de la operación o el servidor no responde."

La configuración de conexión a la base de datos se está manejando mendiante un web.config de la siguiente manera:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=DB_name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Passwordpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxUrlLength="2097151" executionTimeout="1800" maxRequestLength="20971520" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
```

El procedimiento almacenado funciona bien, si hago un profiler y ejecuto el sp desde el SQL Management Studio me trae los datos de forma correcta (Llega a demorarse unos 20-30 segundos, pero trae los datos)

¿Ya que el error indica que se está agotando el tiempo de espera cómo puedo aumentarlo desde el config? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso de que esto no funcione, [aquí](https://happydevops.com/2020/03/05/how-to-resolver-error-se-agoto-el-tiempo-de-espera-de-ejecucion-el-periodo-de-tiempo-de-espera-transcurrio-antes-de-la-finalizacion-de-la-operacion-o-el-servidor-no-responde/) se puede leer otra aproximación interesante que puede solucionar el problema (A mi me lo ha solucionado).

Se trata que por alguna razón se está ignorando el timeOut que se ha configurado desde el config, por lo que hay que forzarlos desde el DataContext que nos sirve para comunicarnos con la BD, en mi caso ha quedado así y funciona con querys que traen miles de datos:

(El valor del timeOut lo está trayendo desde una llave del config)

```
public static T GetDataContext<T>() where T : DataContext
    {
        T result;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbName"].ToString();
        int timeOutDataContext = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timeOutDataContext"]);

        result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), connectionString);
        result.CommandTimeout = timeOutDataContext;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del web.config hay una etiqueta (o debería haber) que se llama `<system.web>`, y dentro de está hay otra que se llama `httpRuntime`, es en esta segunda que hay que introducir el parámetro ***executionTimeout***, el cual es el tiempo en segundos que la aplicación espera por la respuesta. Se debe aumentar según lo necesitado

Para que la aplicación utilice estos valores es necesario que la etuiqueta `compilation` que también se encuentra dentro de `<system.web>` tenga establecido el parametro `debug` en false. En resumen, algo así:

```
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxUrlLength="2097151" executionTimeout="99999" maxRequestLength="20971520" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
```

Se puede leer más al respecto aquí:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8